# mongodb aggregate - match $nin array regex values

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

**Must work in mongo version 3.4** 
Hi,
As part of aggregating relevant tags, I would like to return tags that have `script_url` that is not contained in the `whiteList` array. 
The thing is, i want to compare `script_url` to the **regex** of the array values. 
I have this projection:

```
{
    "script_url" : "www.analytics.com/path/file-7.js",
    "whiteList" : [ 
        null, 
        "www.analytics.com/path/*", 
        "www.analytics.com/path/.*", 
        "www.analytics.com/path/file-6.js", 
        "www.maps.com/*", 
        "www.maps.com/.*"
    ]
}
```

This `$match` compares `script_url` to exact `whiteList` values. So the document given above passes when it shouldn't since it has **[www.analytics.com/path/.](http://www.analytics.com/path/.)*** in `whiteList`

```
{
    "$match": {
        "script_url": {"$nin": ["$whiteList"]}
    }
}
```

How do i match `script_url` with regex values of `whiteList`?

**update**

I was able to reach this stage in my aggregation:

```
{
    "script_url" : "www.asaf-test.com/path/file-1.js",
    "whiteList" : [ 
        "http://sd.bla.com/bla/878/676.js", 
        "www.asaf-test.com/path/*"
    ],
    "whiteListRegex" : [ 
        "/http:\/\/sd\.bla\.com\/bla\/878\/676\.js/", 
        "/www\.asaf-test\.com\/path\/.*/"
    ]
}
```

But `$match` is not filtering out this `script_url` as it suppose to because its comparing literal **strings** and not casting the array values to **regex** values.
Is there a way to convert array values to **Regex** values in `$map` using **v3.4**?

Comment: Pass the value as a regular expression, you are passing it as a string.

Comment: This is the way the values are saved in the db. It's a projection. The regex values are in the array as strings. If I was able to convert them to regex values in the aggregation the match would work. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Your question shows a document. Which projection are you referring to?

Comment: @D.SM this document is a result of an aggregation block. My intention is to add a $match block to filter out script_url's that exists in the whitelist array - but comparing to regex values. Saving whitelist values as regex values is not an option at the moment.

Comment: So what is the projection?

Comment: @D.SM, Why minus one?

Answer (score 4):

I know you specifically mentioned v3.4, but I can't find a solution to make it work using v3.4.

So for others who have less restrictions and are able to use v4.2 this is one solution.

**For version 4.2 or later only**

The trick is to use `$filter` on `whitelist` using `$regexMatch` (available from v4.2) and if the filtered array is empty, that means `script_url` doesn't match anything in `whitelist`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$whiteList",
              cond: {
                $regexMatch: { input: "$script_url", regex: "$$this" }
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ylnIqPU1SS)

It's also possible to use `$reduce` instead of `$filter`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $not: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$whiteList",
            initialValue: false,
            in: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $regexMatch: { input: "$script_url", regex: "$$this" }
                },
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ng7VKPZJJ8h)

Comment: Thanks @thammada.ts but unfortunately my system is on v3.4 and we are not planning on upgrading at the moment. It has to work on v3.4

Comment: @asafg just a little heads-up. From https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy you can see that the support of v3.4 has ended in January 2020

Comment: From what I can find in the documentation I would say it's not possible using v3.4. If there were some way to convert a value to regex (which there are not), you would still need `$expr`, to be able to use in aggregation, which is available in v3.6. The other possibility is using `$where`, which runs javascript on *all* your documents, but it doesn't support aggregation.

Comment: Thanks @thammada.ts. I ended up making a copy of the whiteList - regexWhiteList which holds regex values of the original. When we'll migrate to v4 we will be able to remove this unnecessarily data. Thanks for the efforts!

Comment: @asafg great! I didn't know we could store regex in MongoDB

Comment: @asafg, just curious though, while you have `regexWhiteList` stored, how do you match `script_url` against that list? I thought `$expr` was available in v3.6